# How do you sign an agreement with a "consolidator" for production access as an individual to amadeus flights API?

Tags: amadeus

I'm working with amadeus flights API and trying to obtain production access. One of the agreements is that you sign up with a "consolidator" for ticket sales. How do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read the following article:
https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/move-to-production-amadeus-flight-booking-api

Take a look if you are not going to operate in the following countries:

3. Self-Service bookings are allowed in your country – Unfortunately, Self-Service flight booking is still not available to companies in the following countries:

   Algeria, Bangladesh, Bhutan, Bulgaria, Croatia, Egypt, Finland, Iceland, India, Iran, Iraq, Jordan, Kuwait, Kosovo, Lebanon, Libya, Madagascar, Maldives, Montenegro, Morocco, Nepal, Pakistan, Palestine, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Serbia, South Korea, Sri Lanka, Sudan, Syria, Tahiti, Tunisia, United Arab Emirates and Yemen

For any additional questions about this topic, please write here:

https://developers.amadeus.com/support

Juan Antonio